# Kernel of an unbounded linear functional on Banach space

Tags: functional-analysis

Assume $f$ is an unbounded linear functional on Banach space $X$. Then $\ker(f)$ is a dense linear subspace of $X.$ Is $\ker(f)$ a set of second category ?

Comment: See [this](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/3188/are-proper-linear-subspaces-of-banach-spaces-always-meager). And, nice question!

Comment: Thanks. It seems there exists an unbounded linear functional f such that ker(f) is of first category. I am interested in whether it is possible to find f such that ker(f) is of second category.  Let's restrict to Hilbert spaces.

Comment: See the first answer there. An example is given at the end.

Comment: Thanks again. It looks pretty easy.

Comment: My question is related to the following exercise in functional analysis:                         Let X be a normed linear space and Y a Banach space.
Consider a sequence of bounded linear
operators T_n : X --> Y, Then the set
A={x \in X : lim T_n(x) exists}
is either of first category or A=X.

The conclusion is not true if we drop the assumption that Y is complete. For this I needed the subspace of second category.